# (Ruby on Rails / CSS) How To Make A Blog "Post" Model Behave Two Different Ways?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I'm making a blog like Ruby on Rails application. Blog posts are generated from my Posts model and I'd like them to have two different behaviours.

I've set it up so a post is generated automatically every day. Essentially I want these posts to behave a certain way when first generated (different CSS appearence etc & when they are clicked the user is redirected to edit that post) and when the user has edited this post the CSS appearence is different and when the edited post is clicked the user is redirected to view the post, rather than edit it.

Does anyone have any suggestions or advice on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first and most important detail is to store the status of each `Post`. So add an `edited`(Boolean) or `status`(String) field to your model. When generating the new/auto `Post`, set the `status` to, for instance, "New". When someone edits it, change it to "Edited".

The second detail is to change the view based on the `status` of the `Post`. The easiest way of doing that is something like this:

```
<% if post.status == 'New' %>
  <div class="new-post">
    <%= link_to "Edit Post", edit_post_path(post) %>
  </div>
<% else %>
  <div class="edited-post">
    <%= link_to "View Post", post_path(post) %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Of course, make the HTML the way you want and add CSS rules to the `new-post` and `edited-post` classes respectively.

Comment: Thanks, this is the perfect answer :)

Comment: Just a followup question: I currently display all my posts with the code <%= render feed %> and I'm having trouble figuring out how to integrate this with the code you've described.

Comment: To clarify: the <%= render feed %>  is part of a loop that iterates through all posts, and that line is used to render each specific post

Comment: I don't know your code, but you should have a `_feed.html.erb` file or something like that. That view code I have would go there.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Ryan K's approach of using a `status` column to maintain the current state of the `Post`, but I would go a bit further in trying to keep the state strings from contaminating the views.

Add a method to the `Post` like:

```
def new?
  status == 'New'
end
```

This will allow you to ask the post about its state:

```
<% if post.new? %>
  <!-- Do stuff with unedited posts -->
<% else %>
  <!-- Do stuff with edited posts -->
<% end %>
```

It will also make sure that the state values don't end up getting repeated in multiple places.

It seems like overkill for this particular case, but if you find yourself dealing with more complicated state patterns, you should look into something like https://github.com/geekq/workflow